# pandas series I want to get today's data

Tags: python, pandas

use pandas.series  I want to get today's data
data

```
a=  [{"content": 1, "time": 1577870427}, {"content": 4, "time": 1577870427},
     {"content": 2, "time": 1577956827},
     {"content": 3, "time": 1580548827}, {"content": 5, "time": 1580635227},
     {"content": 6, "time": 1583054427}, {"content": 7, "time": 1582275530}]
```

final data

```
# today data
[{"content": 6, "time": 1583054427}, {"content": 7, "time": 1582275530}]
```

my cdoe

```
index = pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in a], unit='s')
df = pd.Series(a,index)
get today  data
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df.str.get('time'), unit='s').dt.date
L = df[d.eq(pd.Timestamp('now').date())].tolist()
print (L)
[{'content': 7, 'time': 1582275530}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

# Get a new column with the date.
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date

# Subset df with today's rows.
df[df['date'] == pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime.utcnow().date())]
```

Returns `df`:

```
content time        date
7       1582275530  2020-02-21
```

Comment: add `.values.tolist()` at the end of the subset if you want the result as a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import time
import pandas as pd

a = [{"content": 1, "time": 1577870427},
     {"content": 4, "time": 1577870427},
     {"content": 2, "time": 1577956827},
     {"content": 3, "time": 1580548827},
     {"content": 5, "time": 1580635227},
     {"content": 6, "time": 1583054427},
     {"content": 7, "time": 1582275530}]

a = pd.Series(a)

for item in a:
    if(datetime.fromtimestamp(item['time']).date() == datetime.fromtimestamp(time()).date()):
        print(item)
```